# BouncyCastle - how to generate PKCS10 csr in version 1.52

Tags: ssl, bouncycastle

I downloaded bc*.jar files(bcprov, bcpkix, bcmail, bcpg) and put them into my project. But Eclipse cannot parse  org.bouncycastle.asn1.*.  The documentation apparently lists asn1 related functions.

My code:

```
    X500Principal subject = new X500Principal("C=NO");
    ContentSigner signGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").build(pk);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, pub);
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = builder.build(signGen);

Error: The type org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Is this a correct way to generate csr?

Appreciate!

Comment: Yes that's a correct way to code it, although no responsible CA should give you a cert saying you control all of Norway. Note `org.bouncycastle.asn1.*` classes are in bcprov jar, while the other ones are in bcpkix. Are you sure BOTH are in the project? If you directly added the jars (instead of an environment or somesuch) they should both be under Referenced Libraries in Package View, and if you expand the bcprov jar, then the ...asn1.x500 package, then X500Name.class, then class (green circle C) X500Name, you should see a bunch of fields and methods; does that work?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is throws because some of your classes has a dependency on `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name`, and this class is not in the classpath. In your case for example `PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder` use internally `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name` so probably the problem is there.

The thing is that `PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder` is on `bcpkix.jar` and `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name` is on `bcprov.jar`, so simply add `bcprov.jar` to your classpath.

Anyways if you want to generate a certificate signing request using java maybe it's easy using directly `keytool` which is a tool distributed with JVM, and it's located on `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`. There are a lot of information on internet about how to generate a csr using keytool you can search or if you prefer to show one you can take a look [here](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-java.htm)

Hope this helps,